# Accessing global variable of C++ code from Python

Tags: python, c++, user-interface, system, global

I have written a Python code for GUI. I am calling that python script from c++ code using "system". I want to access the global variable of c++ code from python script to plot the same. I tried by passing the address of the variable to python, but that doesn't seem to work fine. can anyone suggest a proper way of getting the c++ variable from python?

In c++:

```
 system("python3 /home/mosssiac/Desktop/Preethi/GUI/basic_frame_may_21_2019.py".c_str());
```

Comment: How about passing command line arguments to Python script? Certainly much easier task than sharing memory between processes.

Comment: Btw. C++ is not Python. You cannot call methods on string literal. And the method you're trying to call would be useless, you already have a C-style string (in the form of literal).

Comment: I could only pass variables of string datatype to python. So, I thought of sending the address as a string and again convert that into hex in python end. But when I try to access the address, it was not showing anything.

Comment: If you start another executable out of one process with `system()`, this might become another process. I hardly doubt that an address of first process is valid in second. Furthermore, I'm not sure whether address virtualization makes the address of first process completely useless in second. For communication between processes, you would need [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). This in mind, I would understrike what was already said by @Yksisarvinen.